# Basic Message Queue System (AWS SQS)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I need to develop a back-end that will send messages with SQS to end users. The end user will be running an Android app that will poll for SQS messages meant for their device only, I do not want them to be able to see messages meant for other devices. Once the Android device performs work received from the initial polling, the device will send the result back to the queue. I am looking for suggestions as to how to set this up. Should I use a new queue for each user? If I should use one queue per user do I have the user's device create the queue? I am not familiar with the procedure so I'd like a basic flow of how this is normally done. Thanks

Comment: SQS seems likely to be the wrong tool for this task.  You're going to be eating battery and bandwidth on behalf of your users, polling SQS.  Using SNS to notify the device of a waiting message would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS isn't really designed for this and wouldn't be the most cost effective or optimum design. If you have lots of users, you could end up paying unnecessary costs related to SQS requests.

What you need is Simple Notification Service (SNS). SNS has lots of super cools features and supports a wide range of protocols and platforms. As mobile notifications are one of the most popular use cases for SNS, there is a whole section on it in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html). Once you've got the core concepts down, you should take a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send.html).

Best of luck!